# Configuring Atlantis ( Error: This repo is not allowlisted for Atlantis.)

Tags: jenkins, terraform, atlantis

I'm very new to the atlantis stuff, apologies in advance if this question is silly.

I have a requirement to get Atlantis up and running on our private infrastructure. I've installed atlantis v0.23.5 in jenkins machine and our SCM is gitlab enterprise. as of now all our jenkins machines can pull code from gitlab and execute terraform & terragrunt as required.

I've followed the runatlantis.docs for installting the atlantis, setting up the webhook secret,etc. I'm succesfully able to reach the atlantis on port 4141. I've created a internal repo in gitlab for testing purpose which has main.tf, variables.tf and main.tfvars also I've created new branch called testing1 and created a merge request. When I comment atlantis plan or help I straight away get
 `Error: This repo is not allowlisted for Atlantis.`

below is my atlantis_config.sh

```
atlantis server \
--atlantis-url="https://private_ip:4141" \ 
--gitlab-hostname="https://gitlab.private.cloud" \
--gitlab-user="git_user" \
--gitlab-token="ABCDEFGHIKJLETCj" \
--gitlab-webhook-secret="abcdefgh123456789" \
--repo-allowlist="*" \
--repo-config="./repos.yaml"
```

below is my atalntis.yaml

```
version: 3
projects:
- dir: ./dev/aws/service/region/atlantis
  workflow: custom1 # could also be custom2 OR default
  autoplan:
    enabled: true
```

below is my repos.yaml file

```
repos:
- id: /.*/
  allowed_overrides: [workflow]
  pre_workflow_hooks:
    - run: "cat ~/atlantis/atlantis.yaml > atlantis.yaml"
workflows:
  custom1:
    plan:
      steps:
      - init
      - run: terraform init
      - run: terraform plan -var-file=testing.tfvars
    apply:
      steps:
      - run: terraform apply -var-file=testing.tfvars
```

Git version: 2.39.2
Terraform version: 1.0.7
atantis version: 0.23.5

Can anyone please suggest how to overcome the error and the get the outputs in comment section

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score -1):

please pass something like this instead of *

github.com/yourgithub_userid/*

Please try with one repo and then move to allow allow under your account

Comment: Please describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).